# How to collect/compare data from shuffled arrayList(int)?

Tags: arrays, shuffle

Count is an int vaule user enters. Count is 5 for the example below.

```
 ArrayList<Integer> newArray = new ArrayList<>(); 

for (int i =0; i< count; i++){
    newArray.add(i); 

}

for (int j =0; j<=3; j++){
    Collections.shuffle(newArray);
    System.out.println(newArray.toString());
}
```

Output:

```
Shuffle Array
[2, 1, 0, 3, 4]
[4, 1, 2, 3, 0]
[1, 4, 2, 3, 0]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Now if I out the arrayList outside the for loop, I only get the last array:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

How do I access the previous array when you're outside the loop that shuffles it?

I'm guessing it's impossible to do it outside the loop?
An example with small arrays on how to access those values would be appreciated.

Comment: Which shuffled versions of the array do you need?

Comment: I need all of them because I'm trying to collect data on how many times a specific number let's say 5 occurs in column1 and then how many times 3 occurs in column 2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the shuffle results inside another `ArrayList`

```
int count = 5;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> shuffledArrays = new ArrayList<>();

for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++){
    ArrayList<Integer> newArray = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        newArray.add(i);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(newArray);
    shuffledArrays.add(newArray);
}

for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
    System.out.println(shuffledArrays.get(j).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store each shuffled `ArrayList` in a `List`:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

// create the original list only once
ArrayList<Integer> oldArray = new ArrayList<>(); 
for (int i =0; i< count; i++){
    oldArray.add(i);
}

// shuffle original list and store each one
for (int j=0; j < 3; ++j) {
    List<Integer> newArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(oldArray);
    Collections.shuffle(newArray);
    list.add(newArray);
    System.out.println(newArray.toString());
}
```